# Adding the PHP rand function to this code

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I go about making these items appear in a random order every time??

```
            <?php
            for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $nameN = "name{$i}";
            $$nameN = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ch_client_name{$i}", TRUE);
            // or $name[$i], if you can
            ?>

           <li data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php echo $clientterms; ?> portfolio-item" data-type="<?php echo $clientterms; ?>">
               <?php echo $$nameN; ?> 
           </li>

           <?php
           } ?>
```

Comment: Variable variables? Why? There is nearly no place for those in PHP, seriously. Why not just use normal arrays - it's less hacky overall...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $r = rand(0, count($numbers) - 1);
  $nth = $numbers[$r];
  unset ($numbers[$r]); 
  array_unshift ($numbers, array_shift ($numbers)); 
  //Other part of the code
```

should work. It basically picks a random not-shown item, and removes it from array. `$nth` will store which is the **real** number of item.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add each client to different meta value ? You can add all clients to one meta value - ch_client_name - it will be array. This will simplify your structure.

If you change your structure, I suggest firstly get meta values as array, then use shuffle and iterate through array.

```
$clientNames = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "ch_client_name");
shuffle($clientNames);

foreach ($clientNames as $clientName){....
```